# not getting result from ActionResult with $.get

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using a jquery get to try and refresh a partialView and its not working.  Do I atleast have the syntax right?  I'm new to c#

//my javascript is (works fine)

```
function takeSquare(square) {
   var x = $(square).attr('x');
   var y = $(square).attr('y');

    alert(x + y);

$.get("Home/updateBoardSquare", { posX: y, posY: y }, function (html) {
    $("#gameBoard").replaceWith(html);
});

alert(html);
}
```

and my c# is

```
 public ActionResult updateBoardSquare(int posX, int posY){

        String boardHtml = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 15; k++) {

                if (board[i, k] == null)
                    board[i, k] = new BoardSquare(i, k);

                if (i == posX && k == posY) 
                    board[posX, posY].takeSquare((String) Session["color"]);

                boardHtml += board[i, k].getHtml();
            }
        }

        ViewData["board"] = boardHtml;

        return PartialView();

    }
```

I'm just not getting anything at all from the get statement

Comment: Your posted data is  { posX: y, posY: y }. Should it be  { posX: x, posY: y } ?

Answer (score 1):

Internet explorer can't handle relative urls.

Use this:

```
function takeSquare(square) {
   var x = $(square).attr('x');
   var y = $(square).attr('y');

    alert(x + y);

$.get('@Url.Action("Home", "updateBoardSquare")', { posX: y, posY: y }, function (html) {
    $("#gameBoard").replaceWith(html);
});


}
```

See? I'm using `@Url.Action` to let Razor generate the url to use. The upside is that it works both for root web sites and applications which are hosted in virtual directories.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just not getting anything at all from the get statement

You are attempting to use the `html` variable outside of the success callback.

Also you seem to have inverted use the `y` variable twice:

```
$.get("Home/updateBoardSquare", { posX: x, posY: y }, function (html) {
    $("#gameBoard").replaceWith(html);
    alert(html);
});
```

Comment: What's not working? Is the controller action being hit? Did you analyze the AJAX request in FireBug? What's the response sent from the server?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could look that up in firebug.  It wasn't even getting there.  For some reason I didn't need Home/updateBoardSquare   just updateBoardSquare